# El uso de "de no" al principio del tercer condicional

Tags: gramática, subjuntivo, tiempos-verbales

Encontre este ejemplo en el libro "La Víctima Número Ocho" (España)":

"***De no habérsele agotado** las existencias de pintura, **habría dejado** en la quiebra a todos los chicos de la zona.*"

Supongo, que sería la siguiente traduccion al inglés:

*"Had he not run out of paint supplies, he would have bankrupted all the boys in the area."*

OR

*"If he had not run out of pain supplies, he would have bankrupted all the boys in the area."*

También encontré en otro fuente (pero no en el tercer condicional):

***De no ser** por el trabajo de documentación e investigación llevado a cabo al escribir el artículo sobre las mejores recetas de la cocina riojana, **no me habría topado** con la receta de pisto riojano.*

Preguntas:

1. ¿Cuándo se puede usar esta estructura "*de no*" al empezar una oración?
2. ¿Sería correcta la traducción al inglés como "*If not for the...*"? Al menos en el segundo ejemplo "*de no ser*"?
3. ¿Sería posible usar esta estructura en una oración positiva, por ejemplo "***De** habérsele agotado...*"?
4. En el primer ejemplo, ¿se puede sustituir "*De no habérsele agotado*" por "*Si no se le hubiera agotado*"?
5. En el segundo ejemplo, ¿cómo se puede sustituir "*De no ser por el trabajo*"? ¿Con "*Si no fuera por el trabajo*" o con "*Si no hubiera sido por el trabajo*"?

P.S. Por adelantado les agradecería que corregieran los errores en mi letra, en caso de que los haya.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Las construcciones condicionales con "de" son coloquiales.

El Diccionario de la RAE dice en la acepción (12) de "de":

> 12. prep. U. seguida de infinitivo con valor condicional. *De saberlo antes, habría venido.*

Mi experiencia como hablante es que "de" va seguido de infinitivo simple con sentido condicional para referirse al presente o futuro con el significado de "en caso de" (*in the event that*), y en general va seguido de infinitivo perfecto para referirse al pasado. Para mí, la oración del DRAE sonaría mucho más natural así:

- De haberlo sabido antes, habría venido.

La construcción "de no ser por" es casi una frase hecha, similar a "si no hubiera sido por"(*had it not been because of / due to...*)

Las construcciones referidas al pasado me resultan más frecuentes y naturales que las referidas al presente, como:

- De no venir, avísame. (=En caso de que no vengas, avísame.)

Comment: Ahora todo entiendo. Solo quiero precisar sobre el punto 4. Ahora creo que se puede sustituir "De no habérsele agotado" por "Si no se le hubiera agotado". ¿Es correcto?

Comment: Sí, es correcto.